# How to maintain the same size of autocompleteview() irrespective of orientation (i.e. portrait or landscape)?

Tags: android

I have tried separate layout folder(layout-land in which I have created xml file for landscape view having same name as compared to portrait view's xml file ) but it works only when I have hold the phone in landscape(horizontal) but when I hold it in vertical position, it distorted. How to maintain the same size of autocompleteview() irrespective of orientation (i.e. portrait or landscape)?

Comment: I hope you created a seperated folder called `layout-land` and made an alternate `xml`....its not `layout-land.xml`

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have done it by using Linearlayout with Horizontal Orientation.